# Process a list of million files on Airflow in parallel

Tags: python, multiprocessing, airflow

I have an ETL pipeline which consists of the following tasks:

1. crawl a website to collect urls to csv files
2. download all the files from url's of Step-1
3. process each file so downloaded in Step-2

I have a python function for each of these steps, let's call them `{f1,f2,f3}`

With the `multiprocessing` module, and `Pool.map` call, I can fire `n processes` for both `f2, f3`

I was converting this entire script into an Airflow DAG. My question is assuming, a scale of million files, I would like to especially in Step-3 use my entire cluster of Celery workers to process the files in parallel.

For example, let's say I have 100 celery worker nodes, with each node having 2 cores which gives me 200 cores- I would like to process say, at least 100 files in parallel.

How do I do this?

Comment: This might not be related to your question but I have seen you asked @vurmux below about having one task to do this. What if you use BashOperator to execute a Python file that uses multiprocessing?

Comment: @ApichartThanomkiet The purpose of this question was to figure out if Airflow can be used to distribute tasks across nodes. While you can perfectly use multiprocessing, it will be restricted to just one node- hence you don't get the advantage of distributed computing. Other thing would be tracking those individual tasks. Unless you go with dynamic DAG's there isn't any other option, and Dynamic DAGS mess up the UI terribly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Airflow can be used in thousands of dynamic tasks, but it should not. Airflow DAGs are supposed to be pretty constant. You still can use Airflow, for example, to process the whole bunch of scraped data and use this info in your ETL process later.

Large amount of dynamic tasks can lead to DAG runs like it:

[image]

Which leads to many garbage info both in GUI and in log files.

I recommend to build your task system on top of [Celery library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyz6P.png) (don't mess up with the `CeleryExecutor` in Airflow, because Airflow can be used on top of Celery). It is a task queue that is focused on millions of real-time tasks:

> Celery is used in production systems to process millions of tasks a day.

Celery is written on Python, is production-ready, stable and is incredibly scalable. I think it is the best tool to solve your problem.

---

But if you really want to use only Airflow, you can read [this](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags/) article (about dynamic DAG generation) and [this](https://medium.com/@ashishap89/dynamic-dependency-generation-with-apache-airflow-scheduler-eac45444b088) article (about dynamic tasks generation inside the DAG).

Comment: What, if I don't want to add dynamic tasks? Rather, one task which scales to several nodes, which is what I want. It seems airflow might not support it

Comment: If you want it, IMO you don't need Airflow. Just write Celery(library)-based script and run it. It will be faster and more useful.

Comment: That is what I was thinking as well. Just that I am already going to use Airflow anyway, and was trying to think if there was someway I could use the same framework to solve this use particular use case as well.

Comment: @sudeepgupta90 can you share with us what solution you used? Did you stick with Airflow?

Comment: @ApichartThanomkiet I used Celery to do this job